# Cloud Endpoints Portal is deprecated - alternatives?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Cloud Endpoints Portal is being [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/dev-portal-overview). Is there a new alternative to view and test your api? It doesn't say anything about what is available on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no more public information beyond what is stated in the [Cloud Endpoints Portal deprecation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/dev-portal-overview) documentation.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Google Cloud Endpoints is not being deprecated. The Cloud Endpoints Portal is.

Comment: @Micro I have edited my answer for clear understanding.